# Validate email once field in inactive

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So I'm not really sure how to word this, but I have a form and I also pass that to my jQuery, then to PHP. So it's basically an AJAX request. Now what I want to do is when the user click it, enters the email, then click ***off*** the field or moves to the next it'll check if it's valid. So far it checks as the user types which I find annoying. Here's what I got so far.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#email").keyup(function() {
        var email = $("#email").val(); 
        $.post("../classes/check.php", {email:email},
            function(result) {
                if(result == 0) {
                    //Email valud
                    console.log("Good");
                }
                else {
                    //Email invalid 
                    $("#email").css('border', '2px solid red');
                }
            });
     });
});
```

Any ideas? I think it has to do with `keyup`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you want to do it onblur.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#email").blur(function() {
    var email = $("#email").val(); 
    $.post("../classes/check.php", {email:email},
        function(result) {
            if(result == 0) {
                //Email valud
                console.log("Good");
            }
            else {
                //Email invalid 
                $("#email").css('border', '2px solid red');
            }
        });
   });
});
```

`keyup` is called everytime that you press a key, which isn't quite the right event to listen for, for a field validation.  the `blur` event is called when an input loses `focus`. or like you say, when we go from one field to another.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of firing this using keyup, try using blur.  You're binding the events in the sub-function to fire anytime someone releases a key which is why it's firing every time someone types.  Blur might not be exactly what you're looking for but it will probably get you close: http://api.jquery.com/blur/

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using JQuery, you could add the `required` tag to the input, and make it of type `email`.  JQuery will handle the validation for you and show the appropriate error messages to the user.

```
<input type="email" id="email" required />
```